# How to return the value from retrofit onResponse?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner with Android and have written a simple retrofit example:

```
    LOGININTERFACE mAPISERVICE;
    mAPISERVICE= LOGINGENERATOR.getAPIServices();
    mAPISERVICE.savePost("0016642902","0016642902","password").enqueue(new Callback<LGOINMODEL>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LGOINMODEL> call, Response<LGOINMODEL> response) {
            LGOINMODEL output=response.body();
                            if(response.isSuccessful())
                test[0] ="behzad behzad behzad";
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LGOINMODEL> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

But in this line:

```
     test[0] ="behzad behzad behzad";
```

It can't return a value, and have not read any tutorials, examples, or other posts on Stack Overflow, and so still cannot solve this problem.

Comment: you want to return the `test` array?

Comment: who's `LGOINMODEL` ?

Answer (score 1):

you need a callback so whenever you make a call to this function to get the values from the server you can pass the callback and when results are there it can give you back.

*Callback interface*

**MyResultsListener**.java

```
public interface MyResultsListener{

  public void onData(LGOINMODEL loginModel);
  public void onFailed();

}
```

now suppose the call you made is in some function then pass the MyResultsListener reference as a parameter to get back the results.

```
public void makeServerCall(MyResultsListener listener){

LOGININTERFACE mAPISERVICE;
    mAPISERVICE= LOGINGENERATOR.getAPIServices();
    mAPISERVICE.savePost("0016642902","0016642902","password").enqueue(new Callback<LGOINMODEL>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LGOINMODEL> call, Response<LGOINMODEL> response) {
            LGOINMODEL output=response.body();
                            if(response.isSuccessful())
                test[0] ="behzad behzad behzad";
                //for getting back data to calling class or function
                listener.onData(output);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LGOINMODEL> call, Throwable t) {
                //for failure handling
                listener.onFailed();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for pay attention to my problem,i want to makeServerCall return a string value,how can i do that?

Comment: You can not return a string value from makeservercall since it's a asynchronous code and results will be available after successful api call which will not be available immediately that's why we are using call back to get data when ever it's available using listener.onData()

Comment: Yes sure that's we are doing currently whatever is coming in response we are passing it as a parameter in listener.onData(output) this will be available where you have passed the reference.

Comment: thanks,i want write simple makeServerCall method to get any data from server,and want to when my friend call my makeServerCall method,return to my friend any data,can you write code for that plan?thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

With retrofit2 is possible make synchronous call:

```
mAPISERVICE = LOGINGENERATOR.getAPIServices();
Callback<LOGINMODEL> mLOGINMODEL = mAPISERVICE.savePost("0016642902","0016642902","password");
Response<LOGINMODEL> response = mLOGINMODEL.execute();
...
```

however, synchronous requests trigger app crashes on Android 4.0 or newer. You’ll run into the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` error.

More information [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests).